# What is the precedence order in thunderbird message filtering?

Tags: thunderbird, email-filter

Will these filters work as intended?

- If conditions A & B ==> folder X
- If condition A ==> folder Y
- Others, no processing

In other words, will message filter rules be processed in sequential order?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, messages will be run in order from top to bottom, meaning that the first rule will be executed, then the second rule may move the message to another folder. Note that a rule can have the option "stop filter execution", which doesn't process any further rules for that particular message.